# Installing Visual Studio times out when installing using the system account

Tags: visual-studio, installation

To setup VMs we use [chocolatley](https://chocolatey.org/) running under the system account (NT Authority\System) to install software. When it comes to installing Visual Studio 2019 ([package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/visualstudio2019professional)) the installation times out. Looking at the logs it seems the VS installer is trying to access `C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp` and failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Visual Studio isn't installing correctly when run from the system account, it could be because the `%TEMP%` and `%TMP%` paths are resolved to the systemprofile locations (below) and VS can't write to them.

- `C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp`
- `C:\windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp`

As a workaround you can set the environment variables `%TEMP%` and `%TMP%` to point to another directory before running the install command. This directory should be the system temp folder `c:\windows\temp`. This should be done in a manner wide such that the VS installer and spawned processes will pick it up. This could be done with `set` [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set), for example:

```
set TEMP C:\Windows\Temp
set TMP C:\Windows\Temp
```

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT thanks for the reminder! I think you have to wait 2 days before accepting an answer. I forgot to check back :(.